# Hotmail DMARC reports show errors in DKIM verification, but not always

Tags: smtp, dmarc

I set DKIM, SPF and DMARC on my domain. I placed on the DMARC register I want to receive reports to see if my implementation of rules it's ok or not, to set a strict rule to say if something it's wrong the destination server should delete the false email.

Yahoo reports are fine and uncommon servers too, but on the hotmail reports I'm receiving always problems with DKIM in one or two emails each day.

X.X.X.X it's the same IP in both records.

The first records says on 9 messages they got a temperror and later a fail.
The second record says that 49 messages were ok.

In other days they temperror result doesn't appers and shows directly the fail dkim result code.

I read time ago hotmail/outlook does internally some kind of redirections, but that IMHO should break SPF too.

```
<record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>X.X.X.X</source_ip>
      <count>9</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>fail</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>mydomain.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <spf>
        <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
      <dkim>
        <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
        <result>temperror</result>
      </dkim>
      <dkim>
        <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
        <result>fail</result>
      </dkim>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>X.X.X.X</source_ip>
      <count>49</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>mydomain.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <spf>
        <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
      <dkim>
        <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </dkim>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
```

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: If this it's usual for hotmail DMARC reports or not. With the information the report offers I cannot see nothing related to which it's the problem for a dkim fail.